# Start-Process do not play well with Start-Sleep

Tags: powershell

My goal is to run several processes and save their `ProcessName` and `Id` for later usage. Here is my code

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$startedProcesses = @()
$processStatus = Start-Process -FilePath notepad.exe -passthru
Start-Sleep 1
$startedProcesses.add($processStatus)

$processStatus = Start-Process -FilePath calc.exe -passthru
Start-Sleep 1
$startedProcesses.add($processStatus)

echo $startedProcesses
```

Output of this script is:

```
PS C:\Users\wakatana\Desktop\> .\so_question0.ps1

Handles  NPM(K)    PM(K)      WS(K)     CPU(s)     Id  SI ProcessName
-------  ------    -----      -----     ------     --  -- -----------
    235      15     3408      14112       0.08  24812   2 notepad
              0        0          0       0.13  21460
```

I have also tried replace  `[System.Collections.ArrayList]$startedProcesses = @()`
with `$startedProcesses = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.ComponentModel.Component]` but I ended with the same result.

Questions: why I do not have `calc` under `ProcessName`? If I remove `Start-Sleep 1` then i got `calc` under `ProcessName`. Why is that? Is this correct way of starting apps or am I doing something wrong? My OS: Windows 10 Home

Comment: for me, on win7ps5.1, your code works as expected - the `calc` string is listed in the `ProcessName` list. it also works with the `Start-Sleep` lines commented out.

Comment: Interesting, Calc appx does have this trouble, it seems like `calc` passes the request to `svchost`, then the Calculator appx launched. In this way, `calc` is not the parent process of `Calculator.exe` which means unable to locate via Win32_Process. The problem remains: `How to get the correct process id of Calculator.exe launched by calc?`

Comment: @Lee_Dailey: The problem surfaces on W8 and above, where `calc.exe` is just a _stub_ executable for the separate Calculator UWP application (AppX package); for more info on the latter, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58733061/45375).

Comment: Good sleuthing, @LarrySong. My answer shows a solution, which, while not foolproof, should be robust enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is unrelated to the use of `Start-Sleep`.

Instead, the problem is that, as of Windows 10, **`calc.exe` is only a *stub* executable for the process that is ultimately launched, and the stub process exits as soon as it has launched the real executable**.

If you remove the `Start-Sleep` call between the `Start-Process` and the `echo` calls, the *stub* process object contained in `$startedProcesses` typically does reflect the stub executable's name - `calc.exe` - in the `ProcessName` column at that time, due to still being alive (albeit only shortly), but you still won't be able to track the *real* executable's process lifetime and exit code through that object.

The real executable's name is `Calculator.exe`, whose exact path incorporates a full AppX package name (a package name, a version number, and publisher ID):

For instance, after launching `calc.exe`, `(Get-Process Calculator).Path` yields something like:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1908.0.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe
```

However, **you can NOT use that path to launch Calculator *directly*** - you'll get an `Access denied` error, even when running with elevation.

Calculator, as an **AppX package (a UWP application typically distributed via the Microsoft Store)**, is most easily **launched by its URL scheme**:

```bash
Start-Process ms-calculator:
```

Note:

- For an automated way to discover an AppX app's URL scheme names by package name or wildcard-based part of it - e.g., `*Calculator*` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58733061/45375).
- The less convenient alternative is to use a `shell:` URL that is based on an application's AppID - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68907604/45375).

Unfortunately, as of PowerShell (Core) 7.2 / Windows PowerShell v5.1, **adding `-PassThru` to invocation of an AppX-package URL with `Start-Process` results in an *error*** instead of returning an object representing the launched process - though Calculator still launches; the **same applies to `-Wait`**:

```bash
# Launches Calculator, but doesn't return a process object
# and reports an error instead:
PS> Start-Process ms-calculator: -PassThru
Start-Process : This command cannot be run completely because the system cannot find all the information required.
...
```

The problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #10996](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10996).

---

**Workaround**:

```bash
# Invoke the *stub executable* synchronously, so that
# the real executable has already been launched by the time
# the call returns.
Start-Process -Wait -FilePath calc.exe 

# Now get the real process object, named 'Calculator'.
# The newly launched or a preexisting instance is used (see below).
$processStatus = Get-Process -Name Calculator |
                 Where-Object SessionId -eq (Get-Process -ID $PID).SessionId).ID
```

Note: Calculator only ever creates *one* process per user session (window station): If a process already exists, subsequent launches delegate to this process.