# How to open installed Microsoft Store apps from powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, appx

I'm getting the list of installed Microsoft Store apps with this command:

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUsers
```

And then I try to open an app:

```
powershell -Command "Start-Process 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2021.21070.22007.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.Photos.exe' -Verb runAs"
```

I get an access error:

```
This command cannot be run due to the error: Access is denied.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```bash
# Use the URI scheme of the Microsoft.Photos application.
# Note: Unfortunately, -Wait does *not* work in this case.
Start-Process ms-photos:

# Wait for the process to exit (from what I can tell there's only ever 1
# Microsoft.Photos process).
# The relevant process name was obtained with: Get-Process *Photos*
(Get-Process Microsoft.Photos).WaitForExit()
```

<sup>Note: That `Start-Process` `-Wait` (and `-PassThru`) cannot be used with at least some Microsoft Store applications is unfortunate; the problem has been reported in [GitHub issue #10996](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10996).</sup>

Using a **URI protocol scheme** such as `ms-photos:` is the simplest approach, although discovering a given Microsoft Store's application's protocol(s) is non-trivial - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58733061/45375), which provides a helper function, `Get-AppXUriProtocol`, which builds on the standard
[`Get-AppXPackage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/appx/get-appxpackage) cmdlet; e.g.:

```bash
# Note: 
#  * Requires custom function Get-AppXUriProtocol from the linked answer.
#  * Must be run in *Windows PowerShell*, because the AppX module
#    isn't supported in PowerShell (Core), as of v7.1.
PS> Get-AppXUriProtocol *Photos* | Format-List

PackageFullName : Microsoft.Windows.Photos_2021.21070.22007.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
Protocols       : {ms-wcrv, ms-wpdrmv, ms-photos, microsoft.windows.photos.crop...}
```

As you can see, the Microsoft Photos application has several protocol schemes associated with it, but the obvious candidate for simply launching the application is `ms-photos:`, which indeed works.

---

**Launching Microsoft Store  applications that do *not* have a URI protocol scheme defined:**

If a given application doesn't define a URI protocol scheme, you must - somewhat obscurely - launch it via its **AppId** (application ID), and the general **`shell:`** URI protocol scheme and the virtual **`AppsFolder`** shell folder; e.g., to launch Calculator:

```bash
Start-Process shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App
```

**Finding an application's AppID**:

- In **Windows 10 and above**, you can now use the **[`Get-StartApps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/startlayout/get-startapps)** cmdlet to list all installed AppX applications or search by (part of) their display name, which reports their AppIDs. Thus, if you know an application's full display name, e.g., `Photos`, you can launch it as follows:

  ```bash
  Start-Process "shell:AppsFolder\$((Get-StartApps Photos | Select-Object -First 1).AppId)"
  ```

  - Note: The reason for `Select-Object -First 1` is that even specifying the exact display name can result in *multiple* results, such as for `Microsoft Edge`.
  - If you're unsure of the full display name, you can use a *substring* to find matching applications; e.g.. `Get-StartApps edge`
- In older versions, you must **determine the AppID *manually***, which is quite cumbersome, unfortunately: read on.

The AppID is composed of the family package name (e.g. `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe`) followed by `!` and a package-internal identifier, which is typically - but not always   `!App`; two notable *exceptions*:

- **Spotify** requires `!Spotify` (as you've discovered yourself).
- **Microsoft Edge** uses `!MicrosoftEdge` (note, however, that Edge does have a URI protocol for lauching, `microsoft-edge:` and that there's also a simpler AppID, `MSEdge`, though it doesn't support passing arguments (see below)).
- As you have discovered yourself, the suffix is the package-internal application ID, which is defined in an application's manifest file, `appxmanifest.xml`, located in the app-specific subfolder underneath  `$env:Programfiles\WindowsApps`; note that a manifest can contain *multiple* application IDs, as is indeed the case for Microsoft Photos:

  ```bash
  # Run in *Windows PowerShell*.
  # For Microsoft Photos, the following application IDs are reported:
  #   'App', 'SecondaryEntry'
  $appManifestPath = (Get-AppxPackage *Photos*)[-1].InstallLocation + '\appxmanifest.xml'
  (
    Select-Xml '//ns:Application' $appManifestPath `
      -Namespace @{ ns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' }
  ).Node.Id
  ```

It's fair to assume for launching the application interactively that the *first* entry must be used, though I'm not clear on whether there are official rules.

To demonstrate the technique using Microsoft Photos:

```bash
# Get the package family name (the assumption here is that only *1* package matches).
# Note: While you must run the Get-AppXPackage from *Windows PowerShell*
#       you can use the resulting package name to launch the application
#       from PowerShell (Core) too.
$packageFamilyName = (Get-AppXPackage *Photos*).PackageFamilyName

Start-Process "shell:AppsFolder\$packageFamilyName!App"
```

Note that since the executable is then launched *indirectly*, the actual target process (`Microsoft.Photos` in this case) isn't guaranteed to exist yet when `Start-Process` returns, so more work is needed to first wait for it to come into existence, and then wait for it to exit.

In the simplest - but not fully robust - case, insert a [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep) command, to sleep as long as you would expect creation of the target process to take *at most* (the actual timing varies with system load):

```bash
Start-Process "shell:AppsFolder\$packageFamilyName!App"

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5 # Wait for the Microsoft.Photos process to be created.
(Get-Process Microsoft.Photos).WaitForExit()
```

A fully robust approach would require more work.

---

**Passing *arguments* to Microsoft Store applications:**

- With the **general `"shell:AppsFolder\$appId"` approach**, you can seemingly pass argument as usual, via [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process)' `-ArgumentList` (`-Args`) parameter; e.g., with Microsoft Edge (run from *Windows PowerShell* - if you have an older Edge version, replace `!App` with `!MicrosoftEdge:

  ```bash
  # Starts Microsoft Edge and opens the specified URLs.
  # Note: Curiously, this does NOT work with the simpler "MSEdge" AppID.
  Start-Process `
     shell:AppsFolder\Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge `
     -Args 'http://example.org https://wikipedia.org'
  ```
- With the **app-specific URI-scheme approach, argument(s) must be passed *as part of the URI*** (`-ArgumentList` is ignored):

  - **Caveat**: It is **unclear to me how you can pass *multiple* arguments** and, generally, whether there is a *standardized* method across applications to embed arguments in the URI.
  - For instance, Microsoft Edge seems to accept only *one* argument: the URL of a site to open. Anything after that one URL is seemingly interpreted as a part of that one URL:

    ```bash
    # Starts Microsoft Edge an opens the specified URL.
    Start-Process 'microsoft-edge:https://en.wikipedia.org?search=wikipedia'
    ```

Comment: Ah, I see. It seems that Photos app just doesn't accept image paths as arguments. it just opens the main page. But how does File Explorer is able to open images via context menu then. Perhaps it expects something like -Path C:\image.png. Task manager doesn't show any arguments on the Photos.exe process either.

Comment: I'm making an open-source modern [file manager app](https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager). With your help I will now be able to add a way to open files in specific UWP store apps, thank you for your contribution

Comment: Ok, well, I have almost experience with COM objects. unfortunately, so I have no idea how to use it in a command

Comment: Ah yeah, I remember you Michael. So you've come to my rescue yet again, huh. Cheers, bought you another coffee, enjoy mate

Comment: By the way I figured you can find the app ID (the `!App` bit on the end) in the AppxManifest.xml located in the app's folder.

Comment: Yep, it seems that the ID is located in `<Application Id="Spotify"`. I will probably have to extract that with Node.js. It seems like the registry key you mentioned doesn't have some of the apps there for some reason

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman: As for the COM issue: I suggest asking a _new_ question focused on that: Given a shell-extension CLSID, how do you find the implementing COM executable or DLL, and how do you inspect its interfaces and members? I' been able to track down the implementing DLL as `%SystemRoot%\system32\PhotoMetadataHandler.dll`, but I don't know how to reflect on it (yet).

Comment: Thanks for the info. You've helped enough already. I will create another question with that exact title

Comment: @AlekseyHoffman. Sounds great; re finding the app ID(s) of an application (there can be multiple): I've added a command to the answer that extracts them programmatically.

Comment: Oh that's great, thanks. I just tested it with a few apps, it seems to be working as expected