# How to get installed File Explorer verbs for certain files

Tags: powershell

I am working on a module for FOOBAR2K, a music player.
So that it can be controlled and used from the terminal, For example `Get-FooBar -status`:

```
Name                     Value  
----                     -----  
Artist                   Antonio Carlos Jobim  
Song                     Amparo  
Album                    Stone Flower  
Current Time             0:09  
Total                    Time 3:42  
Path                     C:\Music Library\Antonio Carlos Jobim - Stone Flower\Amparo.flac
```

I have covered quite a bit of ground. One functionality I need is to add\append to the currently playing playing files.

I can take some songs and create a new "currently playing" list just fine:

```
Get-ChildItem -path ".\Antonio Carlos Jobim - Stone Flower" -Exclude *sabia*,*amp* | Set-FooBar
```

But I sometimes need a way to append to the "Currently Playing List". I did some investigation, in File Explorer, If I right click a file that Foobar is set to handle, there are two entries from Foobar:

- "Play in Foobar"
- "Enqueue in Foobar"

Using `Enqueue in Foobar` on a selection of audio file in Explorer will add those files to FOOBAR's "Currently Playing" list.

I am interested in invoking this verb from PowerShell. I did some searching and experimenting:

This article [Use PowerShell to Work with Windows Explorer - Scripting Blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-work-with-windows-explorer/) I was able to find verbs for folders but passing Files in the same way, returns errors:

```
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject 'Shell.Application'
$Shell.NameSpace('C:\Music Library\Antonio Carlos Jobim - Stone Flower\Amparo.flac').Self.Verbs()
```

Error:

```
OperationStopped:  
Line |  
2 | $Shell.NameSpace('C:\Music Library\Antonio Carlos Jobim - Stone...
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
| Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

I ran into similar issues with answers I found on StackOverflow as well.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See if [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68930448/45375) helps. If so, we can close this one as a duplicate.

Comment: @mklement0 hey that worked for me, `[System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo] @{ FileName = 'foo.mp3' }| % verbs` which returns `Enqueue`, `open` and `play`. Exactly what I needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, but you have to use the `shell.Namespace()` method to obtain the folder that contains the file and then use the `folder.ParseName()` method to obtain the *FolderItem* for the file. Its `.Verbs()` method should return valid verbs for the file.

Unable to copy your file path while I'm trying to answer for my phone so we'll flesh this answer out when I get home to my computer.

Comment: Hey thanks for this, I was not able to get it to work with the application I had in mind but it works for other apllications oddly enough. I will keep this for prosperity though. Thaks allot.