# How to use CLI for apps on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, command-line-interface

So basically, I'm trying to open an app on Windows installed from Microsoft Store through CLI. Like lets say for example, opening Spotify app on Windows. How do I do that? Tried googling around but couldn't find any. You can also suggest your answer for Python if that works.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate (but not python, powershell): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907012/how-to-open-installed-microsoft-store-apps-from-powershell

Answer (score 1):

you could simply make a .bat file. look up batch files, there's lots of crazy stuff with you can do with them, and then there's powershell which is even more versatile.

```
run_program.bat

start C:\path\to\program.exe
```